# Unable to create oracle table with check constraint JSON in 19c

Tags: oracle19c

I am getting error - ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword while creating table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder
  (id VARCHAR2 (32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   po_document clob
   CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK (po_document IS JSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below modified one works(without CONSTRAINT ensure_json) - 
CREATE TABLE j_purchaseorder
  (id VARCHAR2 (32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   po_document clob CHECK (po_document IS JSON));